# Vertical navigation Magic Marker highlight on fullpage.js site

Tags: jquery, navigation, fullpage.js

I'm trying to get a vertical navigation highlight to work on a fullpage.js powered site. I want the highlight bar to follower the cursor as you go over the links and then stay at a link after you click on it and are scrolled to the fullpage.js linked div. Right now, the navigation bar does follow you as you hover over each link, but it doesn't stay at the link once you click it.

I've pulled the navigation code from this codepen and edited it to be vertical - https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/OqrzOe. It looks like it sets the original location of the highlight when it loads based on a class assignment. The problem is it doesn't update those values once you click on a link, so when you stop hovering, it goes back to the original link with the original class. I know it's a simple fix, I'm just not sure how to best update those original variables with the new values once a link is clicked.

I attached a codepen of what I'm currently working with below.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jcbbuller/pen/RzXENN)

Here's the jQuery code for the Magic Mark...

```
/* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */
$("#example-one").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

/* Cache it */
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

 $magicLine
 .height($(".active").height())
 .css("top", $(".active a").position().top)
 .data("origTop", $magicLine.position().top)
 .data("origHeight", $magicLine.height());

$("#example-one li")
 .find("a")
 .hover(
function() {
  $el = $(this);
  topPos = $el.position().top;
  newHeight = $el.parent().height();
  $magicLine.stop().animate({
    top: topPos,
    height: newHeight
  });
},
function() {
  $magicLine.stop().animate({
    top: $magicLine.data("origTop"),
    height: $magicLine.data("origHeight")
  });
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the fullpage.js option `scrollBar:true` and the magicline you want to use requires the scroll bar to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks! I actually not really sure how to do that. The example on fullpage.js that is titled scroll bar enabled doesn't actually have a scroll bar showing.... https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html#firstPage. I'm not an expert by any means so I have to kind of go off other examples and then adjust them to my needs.

Comment: I see what you're talking about. The fullpage.js scrollbar option isn't quite the effect I want, I want the scroll nav to be its own separate element where I can style and have it adjust to individual links.

Comment: The navigation has nothing to do with the option `scrollBar:true`. And yes, there's a scrollbar when using such option and int the example you linked. Perhaps you didn't notice it because of your browser or operative system (Mac for example).

Comment: gotcha, well if the fullpage scroll bar option has issues showing up on updated mac using a updated version of chrome, I’d rather just adhoc a solution that works across browsers/devices.

Comment: Which Mac version are you using? I'm testing it in Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3.
Are you getting a scrollbar in any other website when you scroll?
I'm also using the latest Chrome version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I updated to Max OS 10.14.6, which is the latest, and I'm using the latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari and I see the scrollbar as expected. It seems the problem is in your Mac and not in fullPage.js or any browser. Please check your scrollbar settings in the preferences panel.

Comment: I think we're talking about two separate things. It seems like your talking about a scrollbar that shows up on the side of my browser—a systems feature. I'm looking for a javascript scroll bar function that works within the site using the plugin itself, completely separate from any of the systems on my computer.

Comment: Yes, we were totally talking about different things.
Just check the [scrollOverflow example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) then. It is using the `scrollOverflow:true` option. Read more about it on the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

Comment: Again, talking about two completely different things, scrollOverflow:true in their documentations says "defines whether or not to create a scroll for the section/slide in case its content is bigger than the height of it." I'm not looking for that. I was trying to figure out how to activate a highlight bar on in-site navigation when on certain pages. Nothing to do with overflow content or anything of the sort.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by defining what you call "a javascript scroll bar function that works within the site" or "a highlight bar on in-site navigation".

Are yo perhaps referring to the navigation elements (usually bullets) pon the side? Do you have any picture you can show us?

Comment: Good suggestion, I realized the link above doesn't work anymore. Here's a link to my codepen. I'm using fullpage.js and I have everything working except when I scroll. I'm using the onScroll callback function but I'm not sure what javascript to plug in to get the "Magin Line" to scroll down to the next link as well. https://codepen.io/jcbbuller/pen/orKJvO

Comment: If you are referring to the Magic Line you are using, I've never used it and I do not know its code, so I can't help you there. That's an external element and you'll have to figure out how it works or how to programatically force its position.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best answer, but it kind of works. I recalled the first function on load and recalled the same functions when someone clicks on the links.

```
/* Cache it */
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
$magicLine
.height($(".active").height())
.css("top", $(".active a").position().top)
.data("origTop", $magicLine.position().top)
.data("origHeight", $magicLine.height());

$("#example-one li")
.find("a")
.hover(
function() {
 $el = $(this);
 topPos = $el.position().top;
 newHeight = $el.parent().height();
 $magicLine.stop().animate({
   top: topPos,
   height: newHeight
 });
},
function() {
 $magicLine.stop().animate({
   top: $magicLine.data("origTop"),
   height: $magicLine.data("origHeight")
 });
}
);

$( "li" ).click(function() {
$magicLine
.height($(this).height())
.css("top", $(this).position().top)
.data("newTop", $magicLine.position().top)
.data("newHeight", $magicLine.height());

$("#example-one li")
.find("a")
.hover(
  function() {
    $el = $(this);
    topPos = $el.position().top;
    newHeight = $el.parent().height();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      top: topPos,
      height: newHeight
    });
  },
  function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      top: $magicLine.data("newTop"),
      height: $magicLine.data("newHeight")
    });
  }
);
});
```

Here's an example on codepen - https://codepen.io/jcbbuller/pen/orKJvO. If you have better suggestions please let me know!

Comment: Obviously, I'll have to get more specific on selecting the DOM, but so far it seems to work.